# Multiple beans with the same implementation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a situation where I'm using one possible implementation for a particular bean, and it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public SomeInterface someInterface() {
        if (this.context.getEnvironment().getProperty("implementation") != null) {
            return new ImplementationOne();
        } else {
            return new ImplementationTwo();
        }
    }
}
```

This worked great so far, until a new requirement came in, to use an additional interface which for the moment only `ImplementationTwo` provides implementation, and it wouldn't make sense to use it with `ImplementationOne`:

```
    @Bean
    public SomeOtherInterface someOtherInterface() {
            return new ImplementationTwo();
    }
```

I guess this would work, but I'm wondering if this really make sense because in one scenario I could have both beans basically instantiating the same object. Does that make sense ? Is there maybe a better way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Depending on how it's used, ImplementationOne could also implement these new methods, but throw `UnsuportedOperationException` if they're being called: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html. That works if your internal logic knows not to call these methods when the bean is `Impl1`. Otherwise, it means you'll need logic to distinguish between the 2, you might as well make them separate beans at that point ?

Answer (score 2):

You can always define in each place where you're using particular bean a qualifier:

```
   @Bean
   public SomeInterface beanName1(){ //impl }

   @Bean
   public SomeInterface beanName2(){ //impl }
```

Usage:

```
 @Qualifier("beanName1") SomeInterface interface;
```

Also 'd need to allow multiple beans in your `application.yml/properties` file:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, if you have multiple implementations of a single interface, then you should go about specific bean names as below.

Here implementation1 will be the primary bean created and injected where ever we have the Interface1 dependency.

```
@Primary
@Bean
public Interface1 implementation1() {
    return new Implementation2();
}

@Bean
public Interface1 implementation2() {
    return new Implementation2();
}
```

If we need implementation2 injected we need @Resource annotation as below.

```
@Resource(name="implementation2")
Interface1 implementation2;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me fix the issue I was also facing.